# thinktecture IdentityServer "remember me" configuration

Tags: c#, identityserver3, thinktecture, identitymanager

In the 'AuthenticationOptions', If i set true the propperty "RememberLastUsername", the username is always autocomplete with the previous username that i wrote in the login form.  If i set the property to false, the username never remember the last username i wrote in the login form.

What i want is that login form can to remember the previous userName i wrote if i checked the "remember me" option in the login form, if i do not check that option i do no want that username is remembered next time i will log in.

It is possible with the identityServer properties?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different settings. The "RememberLastUsername" works as you described it -- it just is a convenience for pre-populating the username and it is implemented by issuing a cookie. This is a global setting and is unrelated to the "remember me" checkbox on the login page.

The "remember me" checkbox issues a persistent login cookie for the user and as such the user will no longer be take to the login page when an application makes login requests against IdentityServer.

Comment: im not sure if i understood well:  The only action of "Remember me" checkbox is that if i check it from a "CLIENT A", then if i want to access from a different client, "CLIENT B", then i can access without login ? And if i did not checked "remember me" when i logged in "client A", then when i access to "client B", identity server will ask me about username and password again in spite of i am logged with "client A".   Im right?  (Sorry about my english)

Comment: the difference is client vs. user. the design of the setting is user-focused, not client-focused.